# Methods assigned to class in a loop all the same as last method in the loop

Tags: python-2.7, class, methods, variable-assignment

I am using a method factory to dynamically assign functions to a class as follows:

```
def method_man(cls):
    items = ['spam', 'eggs', 'bacon']
    for item in items:

        def method(cls):
            return 'Here are your {}'.format(item)

        setattr(cls, item, classmethod(method))
    return cls


@method_man
class DinnerTime(object):
    pass
```

However, the method `setattr()` seems to not assign the function, rather it seems to  be assigning a pointer to a memory location for `method` that is being modified at each iteration:

```
In [52]: DinnerTime.bacon()
Out[52]: "Here's your bacon"

In [53]: DinnerTime.eggs()
Out[53]: "Here's your bacon"

In [54]: DinnerTime.spam()
Out[54]: "Here's your bacon"
```

How can I assign the function properly so it isn't overwritten in following iterations?

- Is this a late-binding issue?
- Should I use a function factory within the `method_man` loop?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I realised the issue seconds after I posted: A function factory solved the issue. I put my solution here to aid anyone else doing something similar.

The confusion occurred because I already had a `classmethod` factory and didn't realise that I still required a function factory within the assignment loop:

```
def function_creator(item):
    def method(cls):
        return "Here's your {}".format(item)
    return method
```

So that the code then became

```
def method_man(cls):

    def function_creator(item):
        def method(cls):
            return "Here's your {}".format(item)
        return method

    items = ['spam', 'eggs', 'bacon']
    for item in items:
        method = function_creator(item)
        setattr(cls, item, classmethod(method))
    return cls


@method_man
class DinnerTime(object):
    pass
```

With the correct output:

```
In [56]: DinnerTime.spam()
Out[56]: "Here's your spam"

In [57]: DinnerTime.eggs()
Out[57]: "Here's your eggs"

In [58]: DinnerTime.bacon()
Out[58]: "Here's your bacon"
```

## Refs

- [The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python: late-binding-closures](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures)